# Log integral & incomplete gamma function

Tags: logarithms, special-functions

Could someone please tell me why

$$-\Re\ \Gamma(0,-\log(x))=\rm {Li}(x)$$

and whether it is true in all instances? I would also be grateful if you could point me in the direction of any relating documentation.

Comment: I think we need $x\ge 2$, otherwise $-\Gamma(0,-\log(z)) + (\log(\log(x))-\log(1/\log(x)))/2-\log(-\log(x))$, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-support/-t8xjc_n08Q.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde, many thanks for the reply.